# Collaborate on Microsoft Word 2016 documents with real-time co-authoring on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Real-time co-authoring is a new feature of Microsoft Word 2016: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Word-documents-with-real-time-co-authoring-7dd3040c-3f30-4fdd-bab0-8586492a1f1d

But on Microsoft Word 2016 for OSX I was not able to find how to enable it. I can share documents on one-drive with other people and see their modification. But I can't see their change in real-time (they have to save the document). This feature is missing on Mac?

It should look similar to Google doc: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Microsoft employer's comment/answer on a blog entry about co-authoring, Mac version of Word 2016 doesn't support real time typing yet. Related comment :

> We agree that to have a great collaboration experience, you need to be able to co-author on your documents no matter what device you are using. While we can’t share specific plans, we are working on bringing this new real-time co-authoring functionality to more platforms. Note: you can already co-author using the Word Mobile App for Windows 10, Word for iOS, Word for Mac, though they do not include real-time typing… yet.

Blog entry : [Word real-time co-authoring—a closer look](https://blogs.office.com/2015/10/30/word-real-time-co-authoring-a-closer-look/)

Comment: You can vote for the feature at https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304942-word-for-mac/suggestions/16488847-real-time-co-authoring